# how to bind to a table in order to do update/insert/delete

Tags: c#, azure-functions

**Which approach (or combination of approaches) can we utilize in order to enable us to be able to insert, update, and delete entities?**

There are several ways to bind to table storage:

This works great if you have just 1 entity that you are retrieving and your trigger has all the info needed to query for that 1 record:

```
[Table("MyTable", "MyPartition", "{queueTrigger}")] MyPoco poco
```

With **v1 Functions** we were able to bind like so in order to query (unfortunately this isn't available in v2):

```
[Table("MyTable", "MyPartition")] IQueryable<MyPoco> pocos
```

We can bind with `CloudTable`:

```
[Table("AzureWebJobsHostLogscommon")] CloudTable cloudTable
```

Finally, we can bind with `IAsyncCollector`:

```
[Table("mytable", "mypartition")] IAsyncCollector<MyPoco> MyPoco
```

**Which approach (or combination of approaches) can we utilize in order to enable us to be able to insert, update, and delete entities?**

Comment: You  already know use `IAsyncCollector` to access the output table entity so what's your main problem now?

Comment: How do you delete? How do you update?

Answer (score 0):

Bind with `CloudTable`:

```
[Table("AzureWebJobsHostLogscommon")] CloudTable cloudTable
```

Then you can use the `TableOperation` class to insert, update and delete entities:

```
TableOperation insert = TableOperation.InsertOrReplace(entity);
TableOperation delete = TableOperation.Delete(entity);
TableOperation replace = TableOperation.Replace(entity);
TableOperation merge = TableOperation.Merge(entity);
... etc

await cloudTable.ExecuteAsync(insert);
await cloudTable.ExecuteAsync(delete);
await cloudTable.ExecuteAsync(replace);
await cloudTable.ExecuteAsync(merge);
... etc
```

Full example:

```
public class MyEntity : TableEntity
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public static class HttpTriggeredFunction
{
    [FunctionName("HttpTriggeredFunction")]
    public static async Task<IActionResult> Run(
        [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "get", "post", Route = null)] HttpRequest req,
        [Table("AzureFunctionsSandbox", Connection = "StorageConnectionString")] CloudTable cloudTable,
        ILogger log)
    {
        log.LogInformation("C# HTTP trigger function processed a request.");

        var myEntity = new MyEntity
        {
            PartitionKey = Guid.NewGuid().ToString(),
            RowKey = Guid.NewGuid().ToString(),
            Name = "chris"
        };

        TableOperation insert = TableOperation.InsertOrReplace(myEntity);

        await cloudTable.ExecuteAsync(insert);

        return new OkObjectResult(null);
    }
}
```